Ball thrown by fielder hits batsman’s helmet while batsman is taking a run
Batsman clips ball to backward square and sets off for a single. Fielder throws the ball aiming at the non-striker’s end to attempt a run-out of the batsman who played the shot. The ball hits the back of the batsman’s helmet before he has made his ground but it was not deliberate obstruction of the field. Batsman completes his run after the ball deflects from his helmet. What is the law? It is just a straight-forward single to the batsman in the same way it would be if the throw hit his torso, or does the fact it struck his helmet change anything?

Was the helmet actually on the batsman's head at the time?  This distinction was critical in a baseball play today: https://www.mlb.com/news/justin-turner-s-helmet-blocks-tag ;-)

Yes, the player was wearing the helmet when the throw from the fielder struck him.

The answer to this depends on what match and where in the world.  In England we now have an instruction in the non professional game that any contact with a player's helmet or head is an instant dead ball.  So this would be a dead ball with no run scored.
In the laws 20.4.2.2 says you would call dead ball if serious injury suspected.
In the professional game they have medical staff and its managed slightly differently.

Thanks for the reply. If it is a dead ball and no run is awarded, should the two batsmen return to the ends they were at prior to the ball being bowled. They had both reached the opposite ends in my scenario above.

They should go to the end they were nearest in this scenario.
